# Quantum GIS Standalone Browser

Tags: qgis, qgis-browser

I don't think the QGIS standalone browser is working right on my computer. The only tab I can view is Param.  The Metadata, preview and attributes tab are all grayed out.   When I select a .shp for instance, nothing happens.  I can't do anything with it.

Also the Param tab doesnt just display spatial data, but every piece of data.

The browser within QGIS seems to function fine though.

Anyone know what the deal is here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez7iC.jpg

So FRUSTRATING!

EDIT:  Okay it appears the browser only works inside Quantum GIS Desktop.  The standalone browser does absolutely nothing like I described.

Answer (score 1):

Just expand the folder and click on a **shp** file on the **left** side, and you see the data of the file with all tabs (exept param) on the **right** side.

You get the param only if you have selected a **folder** on the left. Then you get a file list on the right in the param tab.

Comment: the left hand window only displays folders for me.

Comment: Strange. What Operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional SP1 64bit

Comment: Same here, but installed in a path without blanks. Can you try a OSGEO4W installation? It should work in parallel to the standalone without problems.

Comment: I did use that installation.  Installed everything from QGIS to Udig, openEV, MSYS, grass.